# Move all zeroes toward the end -- can't get splice to work properly?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function that moves all 0s towards the end. I'm first counting how many zeroes are in the original array using a for loop; and also splicing the 0s using their indexes.

Then through a while loop, push 0s to the array based on the total count.

I'm struggling with trying to get the splicing to work.. I'd appreciate any input I could get.

```js
const array = [2, 0, 0, 4, 3, 1];
    
const moveZeroes = (arr) => {
  let zeroes = 0;

  for(i=0;i<=arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i] === 0){
      arr.splice(i, 1);
      zeroes++;
    }
  }

  while(zeroes > 0){
    arr.push(0);
    zeroes--;
  }

  console.log(arr);

};

moveZeroes(array);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so it's a common overseen bug that you are modifying the array on which you are iterating,

so try to print the array after every iteration of for loop and you will see that your index is incrementing but your array is decreasing in the length itself, which is causing this behavior

splice is working correctly BTW.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sort()` method.

```js
const arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1];
const newArr = arr.sort((a, b) => b - a)
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: The array could have negative elements too.

Comment: sort can do that for you too and more efficiently

Comment: arr.sort((a,b)=>Math.abs(b)-Math.abs(a))

Answer (score 1):

You just need to reduce the value of the i every time you splice the array.

```
function moveZero(array){
    var numberofZeros = 0;
    for(var i=0; i< array.length; i++){
        if(array[i] == 0){
            array.splice(i,1);
            numberofZeros++;
            i--;
        }
    }
    while(numberofZeros > 0){
        array.push(0);
        numberofZeros--;
    }
}
```

To optimize this I think you can use the sort method as answered by Vaibhav

Comment: Thank you, this along with Vaibhav's suggestion helped me visualize the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If you find you do not have a requirement to modify the array in-place. You can create the array you are looking for like so:

```js
const array = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1];

const moveZeroes = (arr) => {
  const zeroes = 0;
  const arrayWithoutZeros = array.filter(x => x !== zeroes);
  const zerosRemovedCount = array.length - arrayWithoutZeros.length;
  const output = arrayWithoutZeros.concat(
    ...Array(zerosRemovedCount).fill(zeroes)
  );

  console.log(output);
  return output;
};

moveZeroes(array);
```

---

In-place sort solution:

```js
const array = [2, 0, Infinity, 0, 77, 0, -454, 0, 1, 100, -4, 0, -2, 88 ];

const moveZeroes = (arr) => {
  const zeroes = 0;

  arr.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a === zeroes) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (b === zeroes) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  });

  console.log(arr);
};

moveZeroes(array);
```

Comment: hello, thanks for your response. Actually, I can only mutate the array in place. I did use filter, which made this easier; but unfortunately I have to return the same passed array.

Comment: Makes sense. I've added an in-place solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in one sweep. `splice()` is more expensive as it has to move all the elements after the section you've spliced and resize the array, and that for every zero you remove. This code costs exactly 1 write operation for each element in the array.

```js
const array = [1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0];

const moveZeroes = (array) => {
  let writeIndex = 0;

  for (let readIndex = 0; readIndex < array.length; ++readIndex) {
    if (array[readIndex] !== 0) {
      array[writeIndex++] = array[readIndex];
    }
  }

  while (writeIndex < array.length) {
    array[writeIndex++] = 0;
  }
  return array;
}

console.log(moveZeroes(array));
```